# How add react-relay component to the storybook?

Tags: relayjs, relay, react-relay, storybook

I am trying create a **storybook** for my `react-realy` app, but i don't know how to set mockup data for that component. For simple a component it is ok, because i can use *dummy UI component vs Container* approach, but i can't use this for nested relay components, for example there is a `UserList` component, which i want add to **storybook**, i can split relay fragment part to container and UI part to the component, but what if `UserList` children are too relay component? I can't split their when they are a part of the composition of `UserList`?

Is there some solution for add relay components to the storybook?

Comment: What I did was create a separated files to the relay container and to my component even if it's children or not. I did that to all components. This way, you won't worry if it's part of a composition or not

Comment: hey @Grund, have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: I have come to the same solution.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your reply! ;)

Comment: http://graphql.org/blog/mocking-with-graphql/

Comment: it would be nice if anyone has experience with doing this using the `relay-test-utils` library. Im struggling to get a solution to work with storybook

Answer (score 0):

I created a NPM package called [use-relay-mock-environment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-relay-mock-environment), which is based on `relay-test-utils` which allows you to  make Storybook stories out of your Relay components.

It allows nesting of Relay components, so you can actually make stories for full pages made out of Relay components. Here's an example:

```js
// MyComponent.stories.(js | jsx | ts | tsx)
import React from 'react';
import { RelayEnvironmentProvider } from 'react-relay';
import createRelayMockEnvironmentHook from 'use-relay-mock-environment';
import MyComponent from './MyComponentQuery';

const useRelayMockEnvironment = createRelayMockEnvironmentHook({
  // ...Add global options here (optional)
});

export default {
  title: 'MyComponent',
  component: MyComponent,
};

export const Default = () => {
  const environment = useRelayMockEnvironment({
    // ...Add story specific options here (optional)
  });

  return (
    <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={environment}>
      <MyComponent />
    </RelayEnvironmentProvider>
  );
};

export const Loading = () => {
  const environment = useRelayMockEnvironment({
    forceLoading: true
  });

  return (
    <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={environment}>
      <MyComponent />
    </RelayEnvironmentProvider>
  );
};
```

You can also add `<RelayEnvironmentProvider />` as a decorator, but I recommend not doing that if you want to create multiple stories for different states/mock data. In the above example I show 2 stories, the `Default` one, and a `Loading` one.

Not only that, it requires minimal coding, where you don't need to add the `@relay-test-operation` directive to your query, and the mocked data is automatically generated for you using [faker.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker), allowing you to focus on what matters, which is building great UI.

Feel free to review the source code here if you want to implement something similar: https://github.com/richardguerre/use-relay-mock-environment.

Note: it's still in its early days, so some things might change, but would love some feedback!

---

I also created [relay-butler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/relay-butler), which is a CLI that takes in GraphQL fragments and outputs Relay components, including a auto-generated query component that wraps the fragment component, and  Storybook stories (the `Default` and `Loading` ones by default) that wrap that query component. And literally within minutes, I can create beautiful Relay components that are "documented" within Storybook.

Would also love some feedback for it!